# Changing id of string in Android / Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I start out with the example Android Drawer Fragment App.
I go to strings.xml and rename the id of the string "action_example" to "action_additem".
I go to the classes and change all mentions of this string to the new id.
I press Ctrl+Shift+S to save all files.

Still, I get this error in the fragment:

> if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_additem)...
>
> action_additem cannot be resolved or is not a field

In R.java, I see the string ID was not updated.
What do I need to do to update it?

In the R file, I see two entries for this string:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_example=0x7f080005;
    ...
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int action_additem=0x7f050006;
    ...
}
```

Why was only one of them updated and how do I update it to the correct id?

EDIT:
Okay - this is solved. One id was for the action, one for the string.

Comment: Clean/rebuild the project. The R file isn't built until the project is build.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can remember for future use - use Alt + Shift + R to perform safe rename of everything - variables, resources e.t.c

Comment: If your strings.xml has no any errors the R.java file should regenerated automatically. So first check the strings.xml file has any errors. If not the case as Kyle said clean and rebuild the project. For the safe renaming in Eclipse use Re-factor >> Rename

Comment: There were no errors in the strings file. The R file is now gone and it is not being rebuilt.

Comment: Check other resources xml files. Not regenerating R.java file means there are errors in resource files the error may be in layout xml file.

Comment: @reggie maybe post the layout file you edited?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse click Project > Clean...

This should rebuild the R.java file.

Comment: Clicking Project > Clean has deleted the R.java file completely. Now I see errors all over the project. The R file was not rebuilt.

Comment: @reggie then you have an error in your resource files (the XMLs). Make sure your XML filenames are all lowercase.

Comment: There is no error in the resource files. I started with a default project. The only thing I changed was the string id in strings.xml.